# Convert docker run command "--volumes-from" to docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

‍♂️

I basically want to convert the following docker run commands to docker-compose version 3.

https://autoize.com/multiple-wordpress-sites-docker/

I'm stuck with the `--volumes-from` part from this docker run command:

`docker run --name letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion --net dockerwp -v ~/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro --volumes-from nginx-proxy -d --restart always jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion`

This is the closest I could get so far.

```
version: '3.3'
services:
...
    letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion:
        image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
        container_name: letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
        networks: 
            - dockerwp
        volumes:
            - '~/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw'
            - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro'
        restart: always
...
```

This is my docker-compose.yml file, for the overview.

```
version: '3.3'
services:

    nginx-proxy:
        image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
        container_name: nginx-proxy
        networks: 
            - dockerwp
        ports:
            - '80:80'
            - '443:443'
        volumes:
            - '~/certs:/etc/nginx/certs'
            - /etc/nginx/vhost.d
            - /usr/share/nginx/html
            - '/var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro'
        labels:
            - com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy
        restart: always

    letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion:
        image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
        container_name: letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
        networks: 
            - dockerwp
        volumes:
            - '~/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw'
            - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro'
        restart: always
        
    mariadb:
        image: mariadb
        container_name: mariadb1
        networks: 
            - dockerwp
        volumes:
            - 'mariadb1:/var/lib/mysql'
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD= #createSavePasswort
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=db1
            - MYSQL_USER=db1user
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD= #createSavePassword
        restart: always

    wordpress:
        image: wordpress
        container_name: wordpress1
        networks: 
            - dockerwp
        volumes:
            - 'wordpress1:/var/www/html'
            - '~/uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini'
        environment:
            - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=mariadb1:3306
            - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=db1
            - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=db1user
            - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD= #createSavePassword
            - VIRTUAL_HOST= #pasteYourDomain (mydomain.com)
            - LETSENCRYPT_HOST= #pasteYourDomain (mydomain.com)
            - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL= #pasteYourEmailAddress (mymail@address.com)
        restart: always

volumes:
    mariadb1:
    wordpress1:

networks:
    dockerwp:
```

This was the most promising source I could found so far, but unfortunately, nothing's working for me.
https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4379#issuecomment-279567234

How can I convert `--volumes-from XY` from a docker run command into docker-compose version 3.x, and how can I apply it to my docker-compose.yml file?

Comment: `--volumes-from` isn't really recommended these days.  (Which volumes are you mounting?  To what filesystem paths?  Can you guarantee it won't cause problems in either container?  What if, unbeknownst to you, the other image has declared a `VOLUME` for part of its application tree, and that overwrites your source code?)  You should spell out in `volumes:` what exactly you want to mount and where.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comment of @David Maze I could solve my issue. Among other things, I have specified the mounting points. I'm not sure if this is the way how to do it, but at least it is working. ‍♂️ I'm happy with that ‍♂️ Thanks David ;)

```
 letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion:
        image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
        container_name: letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
        networks: 
            - dockerwp
        volumes:
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
            - ./certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
            - ./nginx/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d:ro
            - ./nginx/html:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro
        restart: always
```